# No worse or not worse?

Tags: comparative-constructions

I am going to say I'm better than my friend. What do I say if I want to use the negative sentence?

1. I no worse than you.
2. I am not worse than you.
3. I am no worse than you.

I have my doubt because I'm not familiar with "I am no..." (Perhaps if this is the correct sentence, you could give me examples about "I am no..."?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first suggestion is incorrect. The others are both correct and have very similar meanings, but have slightly different usages.

"I am not worse than you" is a direct contradiction of the statement "I am worse than you". It is most likely to be used as a response to the suggestion that I am worse.

"I am no worse than you" is a reference to the idea that there is a scale of badness, and states that I am better or level with you on that scale. It is more often used than the other (see Google ngram https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=No+worse+than+you%2Cnot+worse+than+you&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CNo%20worse%20than%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20worse%20than%20you%3B%2Cc0 ).

Generally I would use your third alternative.